# HTC Desire 510 Ghost texting

Tags: sms

I am having a issue where my phone would sometimes "ghost text" a HTC customer support called it. I think its just heating up when it happens but i'm not sure of the issue. When I text it would randomly start hitting things I did not hit. I noticed when I blow on the screen it also does this. Any ideas or fixes would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't think I have any idea about it other than heading over to the nearest store to fix this one up ! It might be happening because of some hardware issues which can only be fixed by heading to the support centre.